# the usage of 'very' in negative sentence

Tags: negation, intensifiers

Can we use 'very' in 'negative' sentences?

> I can't go out as it is very cold.

Please answer me whether I can write the above sentence or not.

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely fine. Other examples: It's very noisy. It's very crowded. It's very sad. It's very bad.

Comment: @InitK -- Your comment would make a good answer.

Comment: @Jasper: oh well, I didn't have time to think about "negative" part. If you are a polar bear, then "very cold" is a very positive thing. :)

Comment: "Very" does not have any negative or positive connotations on its own. It's a completely neutral intensifier, so it is very easy to use. Even though it shouldn't be, it is even used to intesify things that can't logically be more intense, like "very unique" or "very empty".

Answer (score 2):

> > I can't go out as it is very cold.

Very doesn't imply a positive or negative but a extra matter of degree. So it isn't just cold outside, it is very cold.

A double negative would be like the "can't not" in the following sentence. The double negative means you do want to go outside.

> > I can't not go out as it is a very nice day.

Note that the following sentence is not a "double negative."

> > I can't go out since it is not a nice day.